# Как избегать ненужных споров?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии

Я ответил на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226242/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8/1226291?noredirect=1#comment2147961_1226291)  мой ответ единственный, автор его принял, но после этого стал выедать мозг чайной ложечкой, то не то, это не то. Я как можно стараюсь держать себя в руках, но я и не хотел бы раздувать дискуссию, получается я ответил а вместо спасибо одни претензии, чего именно хочет автор вопроса я не понимаю, код я писать за него не собираюсь, тем более он видимо любитель холиваров.

Я не понимаю зачем тогда нужно было помечать ответ как подошедший.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первая тема на Мете в Новом году. Начинаем год со споров? :)

Comment: Понимаю что это ужасно, если бы не ответ Виктора, вообще был бы удручен, в моей практике это впервые, так что можно сказать просто ложка дегтя. Чувствую себя виноватым, но не совсем понимаю в чем...

Comment: Daniil Loban, таковы реалии жизни. Привыкайте, если хотите делать людям добро)

Comment: А что вы хотите от тестера? )

Comment: Тоже верно:) Назваться можно и Билл Гейтсом - лучше код писать не станешь. Я лишь хотел показать как не пересрелять на ногах все пальцы, писать за автора игру и думать об оптимизации вопрос не стоял. Тот, кто утверждает, что двухмерный масив устарел может ли вообще оптимизировать? В моем коде массив пересоздается, естественно, проще подчищать один массив чем каждый раз делать новый, но я отвечал на совершенно другой вопрос - как сделать движение змейки правильным, попутно улучшая читабельность кода, понимая -  нет предела совершенству:) Но реакция мягко сказать удивила.

Comment: Да стандартное... Анекдот знаете? *Стук в дверь. Мужик открывает. Стоит женщина с девочкой. - Это вы месяц назад вытащили из проруби девочку в розовой шапочке? [Мужик, смущаясь] - Да, я, но не стоит бла... [Дама, перебивая] - Где шапочка, козел?!!!!* Постоянное - даешь решение. В ответ - минус, оно не компилируется!!! Выясняется - человек просто какой-нибудь `#include` забыл написать, или еще что-то такое же - типа, взял, изменил код, но это выясняется после долгой беседы... Почему-то ruSO многими воспринимается как контора, сотрудников которой можно и нужно гонять, как сидоровых коз...

Comment: ошибится может каждый, и собственно если бы люди не ошибались они бы и не задавали вопросов, таким образом в каком-то смысле спрашивающий ошибся первым, но лучше искать выход чем виноватых) а по поводу вопросов да бывают такие где дадут топор и нужно сварить из него кашу, например кинут только html раметку а по коду думай сам что да как сделать, если вопрос интересный я конечно берусь, но если нет то сторонюсь такого. Мало кто догадывается минимизировать пример воспроизводящий ошибку и выложить его в песочницу. Очень хорошо что тут есть снипеты для демонстрации.

Comment: Плохой ответ тянет за собой кучу комментариев - это нормально. Хочешь чтобы не было вопросов - давай хороший ответ, а не просто кусок кода, в котором непонятно что поменялось и непонятно почему вдруг он должен работать

Comment: я считаю что про точку запятую это придирка была

Comment: @Harry, наверное мужик ответил: "У нормальных родителей девочка в полной комплектации по прорубям не шастает!"

Comment: Все равно если гуглишь трабл какой-то то CO обязательно в списке будет, понятное дело что это чтиво нужно употреблять после официальной документации, но бывает что вопросы тут задают учебного уровня, как по мне задача про змейку - это именно такая, разные задачки попадаются даже более простого уровня, в итоге даже найти нормальный интересный вопрос - нужно потратить время, не говоря про то чтобы дать правильный и полный ответ пока кто-то не жмякнул зеленую галочку))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Как избегать ненужных споров?

Если вы обнаружили себя в ненужном споре, чтобы его прекратить - достаточно просто не писать ничего больше в нем. Укажите, что спор бесполезный и на этом можно прекращать диалог.

### Получается я ответил а вместо спасибо одни претензии

Не все люди вежливые. Не все уважительно относятся к другим людям. Примите это. Вы ещё не раз таких людей встретите.

### Чего именно хочет автор вопроса я не понимаю, код я писать за него не собираюсь

Если вы ответили на поставленный вопрос (по вашему мнению), то больше ничего делать не надо. При наличии дополнительных вопросов, не относящихся к основному, предлагаете автору задать новый вопрос. Если под вашим вопросом автор или кто иной предлагает правки, что вам не нравятся - можете предложить им отправить собственный отдельный ответ.

### Ваши ошибки

1. Вступаете в бесполезные споры
2. Зачем то извиняетесь за собственный код `Извиняюсь это машинально ....`
3. Ждете от авторов вопроса галочки или лояльности. У меня, например, много примеров, когда после моего ответа автор просто удалял вопрос и никакой пользы больше никому не давал. Тут всё просто - вы видите вопрос, если думаете, что можете ответить - отвечаете. Если ответ хроший - получаете плюсики, плохой - минусики, ну или ничего не получите. Пишете много хороших ответов - ваша репутация растет. И при этом никто никому тут ничем не обязан.
   То есть больше ответов - больше репутации.
4. Имейте ввиду, это не только вас оценивают по вашему ответу, но это вы в первую очередь оценивавете вопрос. Если считаете, что вопрос больше не стоит вашего внимания - то нет никакой причины не только что то в нем писать, но вообще его открывать.
5. `Знал бы Вашу реакцию вообще бы не отсылал ответа`. Ответы пишутся на вопросы. Ответ не делает вам другом автора вопроса. Ответ предназначен не только автору вопроса, но всему сообществу.

Comment: в общем да, только п.3 я ничего от него не ждал он сам поставил галочку а после этого я уже не смог удалить свой ответ. вопрос слишком спецефичный не все ищут на СО как написать змейку, отвечал потому что сам не раз ее писал. Спасибо за Ваш ответ, я разделяю его. С удалением вопросов сам сталкивался уже недавно так что чудес не жду.

Comment: @DaniilLoban я для себя вообще решил, что я тут участвую только потому, что это приносит пользу мне. Я отвечаю на те вопросы, на которые хочется ответить мне. Я удаляю ответ только если мне так будет выгодно. Я участвую в той дискуссии, в которой хочется участвовать мне.  Так все остальные коммуникации на сайте становятся проще. Не нравится автору вопроса ваш ответ - ну и бог с ним, для меня это уже давно не проблема. Кто то пытается  навязать свое мнение - пусть где то в другом месте пытается, у меня нет времени на пустые разговоры. Как то так.

Answer (score 11):

Ничего плохого в культурном споре нет. Это нормальная критика и избегать ее не надо. (ИМХО ваш код ок). Если вы не хотите дальше спорить — просто не спорьте и скажите мол "не хочу дальше спорить". Если ответ принят, но автор придирается к деталям — то ответьте как-то так:

> Я рад, что мой ответ вам помог. Если у вас есть идеи как можно улучшить мой код, я всегда буду рад принять вашу полезную правку. Считаю устраивать спор из-за этотог неконструктивным.

Comment: Имхо, вносить правки с оптимизацией кода в чужие ответы - не круто. Если правки несущественные - можно оставить замечание в комментариях, если существенные - лучше создать новый ответ с отсылкой на исходный.

Comment: +1. Еще вариант, *"Если вы не хотите дальше спорить"* — достаточно просто перестать отвечать, или же отвечать через пару-тройку часов после прочтения, когда страсти поулягутся.

Comment: @Kromster Это получается игнорировать. Когда можешь ответить — я считаю это не очень.

Comment: Согласен с yolosora. Если такой спорщик начнет править ответ, может быть еще неприятнее. :) Уж лучше предложить написать отдельный ответ.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Тоже вариант.

Answer (score 5):

> Знал бы вашу реакцию, вообще бы не отсылал ответа

1. Во первых ответы предназначаются не только тем, кто задает вопрос.
   Нужно учитывать, что ваш ответ должен максимально интересовать более
   широкой публике. Как оценит ваш ответ автор вопроса, это дело второе
   и третье, ваш правильный ответ может помочь многим  и, главное,
   сайту, без которого не было бы ни вопросов и ни ответов.
2. Конструктивный спор в тему, часто полезен для тех, кто участвует в споре и для
   читателей. Нужно просто этот спор настраивать именно в такой лад, а
   если не получается, и спор начинает утомлять, лучше просто
   останавливаться или вовсе удалять комментарии, чтобы собеседнику ничего не оставалась, как зажать плечи и удалять свои не конструктивные комментарии.
3. А что вам мешает вообще удалять свой ответ?...  Можете удалить без
   малейшего сожаления. Лучше на все это смотреть с более весомых
   намерений, чем репутация(она придет, а важнее собственное
   удовлетворение от полученных и переданных знаний и информации)

Comment: 1 обсолютно согласен, поэтому переименовываю некоторые вопросы для охвата больших задач и людей. писать разумеется ответы стараюсь универсально но не все вопросы это позволяют. про змейку я оветил автору сначала в комментарии под вопросом, потом в ответе дал пример подверждающий мою логику ну и показал то как бы писал змейку я. 2. буду стараться не отвечать. 3. не знаю как у других но у меня не так много ответов которые плюсанули больше одного раза, поэтому борюсь за каждый но естественно слежу за тем чтобы они были достойными.

Comment: вот мой комментарий под вопросом "я как-то уже помогал со змейкой кому-то, да и сам когда-то ее писал, суть в том чтобы не было конфузов, самое лучшее переносить хвост в новую голову, старая голова становится шеей, Ваш код посмотрю, пока только написал совет)" - этого было вполне достаточно для понимания, но так как автор никак не отреагировал я для надежности того что я обясню свои слова не только словами а кодом набросал свой пример, разумеется без цели писать за автора игру или рефакторить его код. просто в моем коде эта идея лучше прослеживается и меньше шансов сделать те ошибки.

Comment: @Daniil Loban, я не обсуждаю и не осуждаю данную ситуацию, не  считаю, что вы не правы, а  выразил свое мнение по поводу вашего вопроса в целом .