# Бан за объяснение своего минуса?

Tags: обсуждение, блокировка

Вот прошел мой первый за 4 года бан (ура, я нарушитель), что ж, давайте немного порассуждаем на эту тему.

### С чего все началось

Не знаю как на ваших любимых метках, но на моих (C# и WPF) в последнее время очень много "однодневок", людей, которые приходят сюда для того, чтобы задать один простой вопрос и уйти, в большинстве случаев это либо дубликат, либо учебное задание низкого качества, либо вовсе человек не поставил закрывающуюся скобку (опечатка). Казалось бы, на такие вопросы надо кидать голос за закрытие и пойти дальше, но нет, тут возникает две проблемы:

1. У нас очень много людей **не хотят** голосовать за закрытие и часто все это приводит к тому, что вопрос висит с 4-мя голосами на закрытие, а 5-го человека так и не находится. Такое впечатление, что SO состоит только из 4-х активных участников, которые следуют поставленным правилам.
2. Вместо закрытия, на такие вопросы дают ответы. И тут как-бы не понятно, ради чего этот человек подобное делает. Либо он не знает о том, что надо подобные вопросы закрывать, либо он делает это ради репутации, наплевав на все правила сообщества. А зачастую, это доходит до абсурда, когда ответ совершенно не про то, о чем спрашивалось в вопросе.

Вторую категорию людей я часто пытаюсь поправить, написав под их ответами что-то по типу "это дубликат, может стоит проголосовать?" (кидая при этом сам голос). Благо по перечисленным мною меткам есть всего пару человек, которые занимаются подобным, из самых активных `aepot`, этот человек прям жаждет ответить на все подряд, что похвально с одной стороны, ибо сообщество получает много полезной и ценной информации, за которую грех не проголосовать, но зачастую его заносит именно на вопросы, которые следует закрыть как тот-же дубликат, зачастую и вовсе у него ответы схожи с теми, что в дубликате. Бывало даже такое, что он [правил уже закрытый дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878) и голосовал за переоткрытие, лишь бы его ответ не канул в небытие, а потом спрашиваешь тех, кто переоткрывал, а в ответ "[недостаточно уделил времени](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56735271#56735271)", а вопрос висит, с ответом и фиг кто закроет... И тут как-бы сами понимаете, я часто ему пишу под ответами замечания о том, что тот или иной вопрос является дубликатом, стоит поискать хорошую "закрывашку" и закрыть вопрос, но нет, человек всячески пытается в итоге оправдать свои ответы и накопленные ими баллы, что приводит потом к долгой дискуссии, где я пытаюсь доказать что он не прав, а он включает "тролля" и начинает увиливать от этой темы. У нас было несколько таких бесед, где он прямым текстом заявлял, что сидит на SO ради репутации (из-за чего я потом ему это часто начал припоминать). После очередной такой беседы я сказал, что впредь буду на все ответы, где явный дубликат, кидать минусы. Что я и сделал...

Не так давно по WPF [был вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1256608/220553), который касался лишь UI составляющей, где человек хотел разобраться в том, как группировать элементы в XAML разметке, чтоб в коде визуально было видно разделение на некие блоки. Ответил `aepot` (сейчас ответ удалил, не знаю почему), где он затронул все, от MVVM, до привязок, написал целый проект, который был совсем не про то, о чем его просили, но да, справедливости ради ответ косвенно затрагивал решение. Я ему в комментариях написал, что ответ не ясен, имеет много лишнего и что стоит там вовсе убрать весь C# и с вопроса убрать эту метку. Я даже переписал XAML и предложил ему готовый вариант, основанный на его ответе, просто пусть хотя б в начале напишет его, а уж затем всякие MVVM и прочее (если они так нужны). Но нет, меня благополучно продинамили и сказали что-то по типу "напиши свой ответ", только вот мне лично совесть не позволит взять чужой ответ и на его основе сделать свой, либо в корне переделать уже существующий. В итоге я поставил минус за то, что "ответ не по теме", написал про это, он подтер как всегда свои комментарии и, в последующем, вовсе удалил ответ.

Спустя пару дней появился [очередной вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1257961/220553), где автор просит помочь с **регулярным выражением**, вроде задача весьма понятная, метки стоят нужные, но нет, приходит `aepot` и вместо того, чтоб написать решение по регулярным выражениям, говорит "качайте библиотеку и пишите так-то". Причем это его решение - дубликат, "закрывашка" которого одна из самых популярных на SO в метках C#. Я кидаю голос на закрытие, кидаю минус автору вопроса (ибо я ему говорил, что впредь на подобное буду кидать минусы) и пишу комментарий, где я ему поясняю за что минус, поясняю, что вопрос **про регулярные выражения**, а не про HTML, что стоит написать все-же решение того, что требуется, а если он и про HTML, то **это дубликат и стоит вопрос закрыть**.  В ответ я получаю что-то по типу "свалите с комментариев", я отвечаю, пытаясь все же объяснить свою точку зрения, но автор опять включает тролля и начинает говорить что-то по типу "ну чтож, побуду твоим психологом" (лично для меня это оскорбление). В итоге на SO очередной дубликат, за закрытие проголосовал только один человек, а сам ответ получил 3 лайка.

### Разбор

Как я понял (судя по тому, что те комментарии потерли), бан на 3 дня мне дали именно за последнюю дискуссию. Ок, давайте тогда разберемся, что-же там было не так?

- **Вопрос-Ответ** - Я может что не понимаю ребят, поясните мне, но разве такое на SO уместно? Вот если я сейчас напишу в любом поисковике `c# regex <area>`, наткнусь на этот вопрос-ответ, я получу там что-то ценное для себя? Вот я, к примеру буду изучать регулярные выражения, как некий источник данных возьму HTML, не уж то меня этот ответ научит поставленной мною задачи? Думаю, что нет. Я не против если будет что-то по типу:

  ```
  Ваша задача решается так: "<area[^>]*>"
  Но лучше всего, используйте готовые для этого инструменты.
  (описание способа)
  ```

  Это и ответ на поставленный вопрос и подсказка о том, что автор выбрал не самый правильный путь решения задачи.
  Но и опять-же, в таком виде это [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354), в котором есть и про разные библиотеки, и даже про регулярные выражения. Но вот сообщество не голосует...
- **Суть блокировки** - В сообщение было сказано `Хотим сообщить, что в вашей недавней активности нами были обнаружены проявления невежливости.` (предположу, что это автоматическое сообщение). То есть, все мои действия были расценены как негатив. Ок, простой вопрос - **где?** Если для сообщества высказывание по типу "Хватит набивать репутацию, поймите наконец, что на SO такое закрывают" является нарушением "БИНАЙСА", то тогда что-ж я один в этот бан попал? Почему высказывания по типу "Свали с комментариев", "Пошел вон от сюда", "Побуду твоим психологом" (что я лично расцениваю как "ты псих, лечись"), это вдруг **норма** и за это человек наказание не получил? Вам не кажется это странным?
- **Блокировка** - Когда банят, пишется обычно "Дать человеку успокоиться", ок, а от чего я должен был успокоиться? Я вам даже больше скажу, вот именно ситуация с блокировкой меня и "подожгла".

### Модераторы

[image: Ban Info]

Честно, ребят, не ожидал от вас такого. Буквально в течении часа после блокировки я дал развернутый ответ и попросил пояснения по данному инциденту, это было 22 число, вы меня славно всей командой проигнорили. Это что получается, банит фиг пойми кто и фиг пойми за что, пусть сам человек гадает что не так, я правильно понимаю? Тогда в чем смысл вашего бана? Лично я бан расцениваю как "некая поучительная мера", а как это может повлиять на человека, если он без какой-либо информации получил бан и все?

А вам не кажется, что это нарушение "БИНАЙСА" с вашей стороны? Ибо как по мне, игнор - это самой хамское, что может сделать человек, а если брать в расчет тот факт, что вы "лицо сообщества", то это имеет совсем другие краски и все становится еще хуже.

Спрашивается тогда, а зачем мы выбираем модераторов, если они не могут даже выполнить базовые обязанности (проинформировать человека за что конкретно бан и попытаться решить эту ситуацию).

### Итог

Ребят, я не пытаюсь тут оправдываться или еще что, это лишь мое видение ситуации, которую я хотел обсудить с модераторами, но нет, я для них походу "персона нон грата". Что ж, давайте вместе подумаем, где я нарушил это чудесное "БИНАЙС", давайте подумаем, где нарушили его другие, а также давайте взглянем на картину в целом, ибо как по мне, на SO есть явная проблема, которая очень сильно портит качество ресурса. Да сейчас каждый второй считает SO форумом, где он может зайти, задать глупость по типу "как открывать IDE" и уйти (иногда даже не дожидаясь ответа). Да, самые "трешевые" вопросы закрываются, но, а другие? Не уж то то, что я перечислил, это в порядке вещей для SO? Не уж то ответы подобные уместны? И не уж то мы не можем сказать авторам этих ответов, что они не правы? Ведь если мы говорим, зачастую это превратится в спор и наши "доблестные модераторы" найдут лазейку, чтоб забанить человека. Почему сами модераторы не закрывают такие вопросы? Ведь вам нажать всего одну кнопку.

Короче, печально все это, обидно за ресурс, который я когда-то полюбил и который меня многому научил.

---

<sup>Я очень не хотел выносить этот "крик души" на публику, но после того, как меня игнорировали модераторы, другого выхода я просто не вижу.</sup>

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122608/discussion-on-question-by-evgeniyz-----).

Answer (score 17):

Мы не видим точных формулировок комментариев, за которые вам выдали бан, поэтому можно только гадать. Но я склонен встать на сторону модераторов в данном случае. От вас слишком много флуда в комментариях, в котором вы агрессивно навязываете участникам свое личное видение методик программирования. Например: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255949/Как-использовать-переменную-в-качестве-name-для-элемента-wpf#comment2206807_1255949](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255949/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-name-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-wpf#comment2206807_1255949)

> Ерунду делаете! В WPF в первую очередь используются XAML и Binding (привязки). Забудьте раз и на всегда про создание кнопок (UI элементов) в коде!

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255604/Покрас-выделенной-ячейки-в-шахматах#comment2206381_1255604](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255604/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85#comment2206381_1255604)

> что я делаю не так - все, совершенно все. За такой подход в WPF проекте надо бить по рукам!

Это заставляет меня думать, что в данном случае тон был таким же, и, следовательно, бан обоснован. То, что участник фармит репутацию на дубликатах, печально, но не является оправданием для агрессии в комментариях. Возможно, если участник действительно принципиально отвечает на дубликаты и игнорирует, когда ему на это указывают, то по нему также плачет бан. Но для модераторов разобраться в таком поведении сложнее, чем выдать бан вам за "хватит фармить репутацию".

> А вам не кажется, что это нарушение "БИНАЙСА" с вашей стороны? Ибо как по мне, игнор - это самой хамское, что может сделать человек, а если брать в расчет тот факт, что вы "лицо сообщества", то это имеет совсем другие краски и все становится еще хуже.

Эту часть я вообще не понял. Игнор не может быть нарушением "БИНАЙСА". Никакой участник, включая модераторов, не обязан отвечать на любое сообщение. Участие на сайте полностью добровольное.

---

Словом, закрывать дубликаты можно и нужно, минусовать тех, кто фармит на дубликатах также не помешает, но вам следует меньше нападать в комментариях на участников, чьи взгляды расходятся с вашими. Даже когда они этого заслуживают.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122609/discussion-on-answer-by-msdn-whiteknight-----).

Answer (score 9):

Ок, раз пошла такая пьянка, добавлю свои пять копеек.

Во первых, бан автор получил явно не за объяснение своей позиции. Бан, как было написано, за невежливость. Была там невежливость или не было - это не ясно, но не надо мешать в кучу тему разговора и факт бана.

Далее,

> Вторую категорию людей я часто пытаюсь поправить

> я часто ему пишу под ответами замечания ... что приводит потом к долгой дискуссии

> У нас было несколько таких бесед

> Я ему в комментариях написал

> и пишу комментарий, где я ему поясняю

EvgeniyZ, вы наступаете на те же грабли снова и снова. Вот вы 3 раза уже тему с aepot обсудили, не пришли ни к какому компромиссу, вы считаете что в четверный раз получится?

Вот руководства, возможно вам будет полезно почитать: [Как избегать ненужных споров?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11281/179763), [Токсичность людей на stack overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11145/179763).

`а в ответ "недостаточно уделил времени", а вопрос висит, с ответом и фиг кто закроет...` - все верно, это я тогда вам так ответил. Я честно признался что я сделал не так. Вы чего то ещё хотели от меня? Дали бы хоть мне об этом знать.

Если говорить на чистоту, то я спокойно принимаю свои ошибки, у меня неверно отмеченных флагом вопросов/ответов очень мало и их количество меня устраивает. То есть для меня не является проблемой то, что вы привели как пример.

Вы вроде как боретесь за сообщество, это похвально на самом деле. Но при этом вы требуете от других делать то же самое. Это тоже не плохо. Но если вы начинаете уже навязывать другим, что им делать в сообществе, это уже лишнее. Здесь каждый волен делать что хочет и каждый будет жить с последствиями своих действий. Хочет aepot фармить репутацию отвечая на дубликаты - если это не нарушает правила и вы его уже один раз уведомили, что это не есть хорошо, а он продолжает - это уже его дело. Не нравится вам это - минус, флаг, жалоба - вот ваши инструменты. Пусть модераторы с ним разбираются. Сидеть и в коментариях обсуждать одно и тоже месяцами не имеет смысла.

Я, например, тоже могу ответить на вопрос, если мне лень искать дубликат. Я могу ещё и несколько ответов запостить под одним вопросом, если посчитаю это нужным. Вы можете придти ко мне и сказать, что это не есть правильно, и я это приму к сведению, а вот буду ли я следовать вашему совету или нет - это уже мое дело.

Что меня в этой ситуации расстраивает болше всего, это то, что два взрослых и опытных разработчика с хорошей репутацией (я не про циферки, а про мое отношение к обоим) не могут ни договориться, ни тему самостоятельно закрыть, что устраивают тут детский сад. Был бы я воспитателем-модератором, я бы обоим по шапке дал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122536/discussion-between---and-evgeniyz).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122607/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167-----).

Answer (score 8):

Мне кажется, что из действующего модсостава никто не появится в этой теме с пояснениями точки зрения и хотя я очень уважаю прозрачность действий модератора мне кажется, что в данный момент в комментариях мод.корпуса нет нужды.

Евгения мы знаем как активного участника сайта, одного из постоянных отвечающих в метке c#, практически уже заработавший на золотой знак. Всё это заслужено и действительно Евгений болеет и переживает за сайт как ни один из нас.

В метке c# есть свой круг постоянных отвечающий, нас человек десять и ещё примерно столько же постоянных читателей/комментаторов — и это ядро из примерно 20ти человек видит происходящее под текущими ответами в режиме реального времени: как комментарии удаляются, как добавляются новые... У тех кто придёт потом и увидит вопросы и ответы, слегка почищенные модераторами после флагов комментарии — у них будет всё равно немного иная картина мира, чем в голове у тех, кто видит происходящее здесь и сейчас.

Будучи программистами мы уважаем факты, поэтому любим аргументировать своё мнение фактами и приводить ссылки в подтверждение своего мнения — но как раз в этой теме непросто приводить конкретные острые примеры, потому что большинство наиболее ярких и показательных моментов уже выпилено и доступно только на уровне модераторов, поэтому во многом мы просто полагаемся на то мнение, которое сложилось из вот этого постоянного чтения текущих вопросов по месте C#.

В этом топике на мете отметилось ответами чуть ли не добрая половина постоянных отвечающих по метке, здесь нет посторонних людей, кто не читал, не в курсе или редко заглядывает из очередей тревог. Я прочитал все ответы и вижу, что вежливо, аккуратно — но весьма твёрдо большинство отвечавших в той или иной форме высказали согласие с решением модераторов.

Возможно не все из нас видели real time именно тот случай, который привёл к бану — но вспоминая общее впечатление друг о друге мы примерно реконструируем ситуацию, что было "примерно как всегда" — и вот эти искры которые постоянно летели в комментариях между EvgeniyZ и aepot — это же не вчерашняя история, этому больше года точно. То на месяцы затихнет, то то снова вспыхнет — но не первый раз. И обсуждали там же в комментариях под ответами не один раз, поясняя свою точку зрения.

Я не вижу никакого раскола во мнениях мод.состава и постоянных участников — все примерно одного и того же мнения. Мета не является рекомендуемым способом для апелляции на решения модераторов, если есть желание подать апелляцию — лучше это сделать в рекомендуемом порядке. Здесь же по факту произошло общественное обсуждение произошедшего и большинство высказалось в духе "если не буква закона, то дух закона сохранён и всё сделано по справедливости". Думаю, что апелляция на решение модераторов будет тщательно изучена, но поводов для пересмотра решения вряд ли найдётся, разве что мелкие процедурные шероховатости.

Вообще, это весьма больно для самолюбия, когда твоё искреннее рвение не находит понимания, признания, а наоборот отталкивается — и на официальном уровне и в рядах постоянных коллег. У меня подобное было на позапозапрошлой работе, поэтому вполне понимаю.

Возможно, сейчас не самое подходящее время чтобы слушать чужие объяснения что же произошло не так — но я всё же попробую, возможно когда-нибудь когда эмоции схлынут получится немного понять.

Прекрасно когда у людей есть высокие принципы и им твёрдо следуют. Принципы есть у меня, есть у aeport, у других участников — при том, что бывает что порой мы от них отступаем при некоторых обстоятельствах. (Вообще, я не знаю, как можно жить после опытов типа Зимбардо или Милгрэма и думать, что наше поведение определяется принципами, а не обстоятельствами — и всегда под любого конкретного Уинстона Смита можно подобрать обстоятельства, чтобы сломать его принципы.) Но мне очень хорошо помнятся слова моей учительницы по литературе, Людмилы Никифоровны, о том, что очень трудно жить рядом с ангелом — даже если он не пытается тебя переделать.

Когда же тебя пытаются фанатично перекрестить мечом в правильную веру — это вообще вызывает отторжение и неприязнь. Я кажется упоминал несколько раз на мете, что тоже весьма твердолобым фанатиком был по молодости? Шишек собираешь преизрядно, ей-ей, это весьма больно.

Мир вообще не создан ни под фанатиков, ни под революционеров, ни увы под любые другие меньшинства — поэтому порой чувствуешь экзистенциальную пустоту, что ты не "ан масс" и не нужен этому миру. Это очень горько, но с этим ничего не поделаешь — и можно только смириться как с неизбежным, пройдя через отрицание, гнев, торг и депрессию. (Франкл по этому поводу хорошо сказал, что если мы сталкиваемся с неизбежным, то у нас остаётся только одна свобода: возможность выбрать к этому своё отношение)

Вероятнее всего, вы сейчас в гневе на несправедливость stackoverflow и вероятнее всего уйдёте. Альтернатива: понять, что уважительное отношение к другим людям гораздо важнее соблюдения абстрактных красивых принципов. Я вот только на днях опять получил напоминание от tym32167 что я не очень правильно поступил — но это было напоминание, а не требование и в этом коренное различие. Как правило, большинству людей достаточно такого напоминания, всё-таки мы следим за своей репутацией, поэтому другие люди являются для нас важными обстоятельствами, которые влияют на наше поведение. Требование же как себя вести — ну такое... "не говорите мне что стоит мне делать и я не скажу куда вам стоит пойти".

В этом плане у нас в стране давно уже пришли современные западные стандарты общения. Никто не хочет на работе терпеть токсичного коллегу, пусть даже и профессионала.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могу сказать за себя: я прихожу на ru-so для того, чтобы почитать интересные вопросы, порой что-то в комментарии запостить или даже написать ответ — но так весьма утомительно, что приходится в какие-то выяснения отношений встревать. И думаю в этом плане большинство людей такие же: кто-то приходит спросить, кто-то написать ответ — но хочется чтобы это было в нормальной человеческой атмосфере, без скандалов.

А вот буквальное стремление принципам когда оно переходит грань напоминаний и переходит в настойчивое требование воспринимается уже не как что-то хорошее — а как полная противоположность, тёмная сторона.

На so, при всех известных недостатках, система модерации вполне успешно работает. Но мне кажется, что в данном случае, модераторы уже всё сделали что дОлжно и большинство участников (просто посмотрите на цифры голосов на ответах) в целом согласно с этим.

Самое печальное в этой истории, соглашусь в этом с tym — это когда видишь конфликт между хорошими в общем-то людьми. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` Ну, будем надеяться, что всё сложится более-менее хорошо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124718/discussion-on-answer-by-a-k-----).

Answer (score 7):

Штож, раз уж я тут главный фигурант дела "о дубликатах", позволю себе тоже что-то написать несмотря на то что обычно я никак не участвую в жизни Меты. Бан @EvgeniyZ получил после того как я флагнул свой ответ с просьбой модератору "пожалуйста удалите комментарии". О факте бана я не знал и не просил, да и зачем просить? Спустя какое-то время комменты исчезли, и я остался доволен.

#### Источник опыта и знаний

StackOverflow для меня - источник знаний и опыта. В том числе когда я пишу ответ, я сам гуглю, решаю задачу автора. И даже некоторые вопросы авторов типа "как отранспонировать матрицу, помогите, я новычок в сишарп" для меня имеют ценность, так как если я сам ни разу не транспонировал матрицу, я прогуглюсь и напишу код. Мне интересно и полезно. И да, я сделаю пост с этим кодом. И да, я буду просить автора дать фидбэк, потому что 1) мне интересно, попал ли я в требования задачи 2) я люблю, когда стоит зеленая галочка, в противном случае считаю что работа сделана не до конца. **Это моя главная мотивация писать ответы.** Так что предположение, что мной движет репутация - ошибочно, я здесь играю не в репутацию, а в прокачку скила разработчика.

#### Актуализация базы знаний

Есть множество "дубликатов" практически на все примитивные вопросы. Порой подобный новый вопрос видно невооруженным взглядом. Открываешь поиск, а там просто десяток этих дубликатов, и ни одного нормального. Либо ответ дан для .NET 3.5, и безнадежно устарел, либо пост куска кода из 2 строк и никкаких объяснений, либо ответ на смежную тему, изрядно покопавшись в которой автор таки сможет решить вопрос.

Здесь я принимаю решение исходя из того, что **SO - в первую очередь база знаний**, и чем больше знаний в базе, тем больше вероятность что ГуглоЯндекс приведет сюда ищущих пользователей, которым SO покажет свою рекламу и немного заработает на моих и не только моих стараниях. И я пишу [актуальный, хоть и не всегда каноничный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567), за что по типа понятным причинам могу получить выговор от некоторых особо следящих за порядком участников. Сколько людей, столько и мнений. **Это моё понимание того, что такое SO.**

#### Дело "о дубликатах"

Представим себе худшую ситуацию (она иногда возникает, даже с моим участием, не буду лукавить). Например есть новый вопрос, у которого есть явный дубликат. Я читаю вопрос и используюя мотивацию из первой главы данного ответа пишу красивый код и немного объяснений автору. Автор счастливый и довольный за халявный разбор вопроса ставит мне плюс и галку и уходит делать свои дела дальше. И тут приходит @EvgeniyZ, и начинается...

Окей, я не прав, поленился залезть в поиск и закрыть вопрос. Моя ошибка. Но ведь даже отвеченный вопрос можно закрыть как дубликат связав его с оригинальным ответом, который может оказаться даже лучше моего по качеству (но пока на мой взгляд такого не было). То есть, одно другому не мешает. И я сам при этом проголосую за закрытие, даже если есть мой ответ, даже если он отмечен как принятый.

И для меня загадка, как хороший правильный ответ (плохих и неправильных, я само собой не пишу) может навредить SO? С точки зрения понимания Базы Знаний, которое я привел во второй главе этого поста, я не вижу вреда от дачи ответа на вопрос, для которого существует дубликат.

Но если дубликат найден прилинкован ранее, чем ответ был отмечен принятым - я немедленно удалю ответ даже если он имеет положительную репутацию. А если отмечен как принятый - извините, что я решил вопрос, который не следовало решать. Навредил ли я SO? Я думаю все-таки нет.

#### Общение в комментариях

Единственное, что нас с @EvgeniyZ останавливает от того, чтобы вести нормальные дискуссии именно - это лимит символов в комментарии. Считаю ли что все комментарии @EvgeniyZ корректные и ничего не нарушают - нет. Считаю ли я, что @EvgeniyZ нормально реагирует на критику своих комментариев типа "можно было и веждивее написать" - нет. Я пару раз пытался намекнуть, но сразу же понял, что человек слишком убежден в своей правоте, чтобы ему что-либо объяснять, и завязал с этим. Ну а дальше я молча терпел глядя на то, что написано в посте @MSDN.WhiteKnight.

Да я был слегка резок с автором вопроса в тех самых удаленных комментах, с поправкой на ветер: "свали из комментариев" на буквальное "убирайтесь вон из комментариев к моему ответу" (что там было на самом деле - только модераторам известно, я лишь говорю о том, что помню). Да я выразил нетерпимость, не это был не первый коммент, а скорее уже после того, как автор вопроса влепил мне минус. Бесят ли меня минусы? От автора вопроса - определенно да, от остальных - повод поредактирвоать вопрос, хотя подавляющее большинство минусаторов после редактирования минусы не убирают, ну и пусть.

Я больше ценю сам ответ, чем мнение окружающих о нем. Если оно конечно суммарно отрицательное, я удалю ответ, особенно если он не был принят автором.

#### Closing

- Я не согласен, что я не прав давая ответы на все что вижу потенциально полезным для SO.
- Бан - это перебор, хотя у модератора может быть (обоснованно, на мой взгляд) накипело, я не знаю.
- Ответ на вопрос, где есть дубликат никак не мешает прилинковать оригинальный ответ при закрытии вопроса.
- Гонюсь ли я зарепутацией - фактически нет, темп её роста меня полностью устраивает. Репутация для меня - в первую очередь фидбэк самого SO на мою активность. И если SO одобряет - я продолжаю делать то что я делаю.
- Ну а вопрос стоит ли отвечать на закрываемое [обсуждался ранее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4957/373567), к тому же я не отвечаю на закрываемое, на момент ответа оно не является закрываемым. А если и отвечаю, то я не согласен с тем, что вопрос следует закрыть.

Всем добра.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122606/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot-----).

Answer (score 6):

Я хочу высказаться по поводу дубликатов и реагирования на них.

Я видел, как умирают форумы, когда на них начинают активно закрывать дубликаты.

Человек - существо социальное. И он, сволочь такая, задав вопрос, хочет, чтобы ему отвечали лично, а не давали ссылку на ответ (пусть даже этот ответ по ссылке идеальный, а личный ответ так себе). В таком случае автор вопроса может и поблагодарить ответившего, и дополнительные уточняющие вопросы задать, надеясь на уточнение ответа.

А когда такого личного общения нет, то новички перестают приходить на сайт.

Также, новички, слегка набравшиеся знаний, горят желанием показать их. Они хотят отвечать на вопросы (да, это простые вопросы, но для них пока что это норма). А если эти простые вопросы моментально закрываются как дубликаты, то как начинающие могут проявить себя? На сложные вопросы они пока не могут ответить, т. к. опыта не хватает, а простые закрываются...

Так и умирают форумы и прочие сообщества. Да, stackoverflow это особо не грозит, т. к. масштаб не тот и конкуренты уже задавлены. Но всё же, я считаю, не стоит мгновенно закрывать дубликаты. Нужно подождать пару дней, дав возможность новичкам ответить, проявить себя. Если спустя пару дней ответов нет - тогда можно закрыть.

Конечно, позволять отвечать на дубликаты следует лишь начинающим, у которых репутации нет или совсем мало. Если её уже тысячи, то можно и попенять такому отвечающему.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122610/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-petrov-----).